# How to type this arrow is MathStack Exchange?

Tags: arrows, mathjax

**Problem** I would like to type some extensible right double arrows with texts above it. But I don't know how to do it in MathStack Exchange(which uses MathJax).I have attached an example in the picture below. I used extarrows.sty package to produce these arrows in Latex.

Btw, I don't know how to tag this question or if I am putting it in the right place...So I just tagged it randomly.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! However, I'm afraid you are in the wrong place since this is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @cfr why is this off topic though? I was recommended to ask this question here by the people from Math Stack exchange

Comment: Not everything doable with LaTeX packages has been implemented in MathJax, which uses a completely different model for getting its output and only shares the syntax with TeX/LaTeX. So asking here is off-topic. A specialized MathJax forum is the right place.

Comment: @DaqianSun the Maths SE people misled you, I'm afraid. MathJax is off-topic as it is not TeX-based.